# Pass 2 variables through angularjs $routeProvider

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

i'm trying to pass 2 variables with $routeProvider :

```
.when('/edition_etude/:idEtude/:domaine', {
    templateUrl: 'vues/edition_etude.html',
    controller: 'edition_etude'
})
```

And my function :

```
$scope.editionEtude= function(etude) {
    var idEtude = etude.id_etude;
    $location.path('/edition_etude/'+idEtude+'&domaine='+domaine);
}
```

Finallly, i'm supposed to get the 2 variable in the destination contrlller like this :

```
monApp.controller("edition_etude", function($scope,$http,$routeParams,serviceDepartements,serviceEnseignes,serviceType_etude,serviceRegions,serviceMaxid,serviceCategorie_magasin) {

var idEtude = $routeParams.idEtude;
var domaine = $routeParams.domaine;
```

It works very well as long as i use 1 variable, but doesent work as soon as i try 2 variables .

This is the code when its working :

```
$routeProvider.when('/edition_etude/:idEtude', {
    templateUrl: 'vues/edition_etude.html',
    controller: 'edition_etude'
});
```

Then the controller who fires the event:

```
$scope.editionEtude     = function(etude){
    var idEtude = etude.id_etude;
    $location.path('/edition_etude/'+idEtude);
}
```

And finally im getting correctly the idEtude ar in y new controller here :

```
var idEtude = $routeParams.idEtude;
```

I don't want to use a service! it's NOT a duplicate, I checked all others answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$location.path('/edition_etude/'+idEtude+'/'+domaine);
```

You don't have to specify the name of the params

Comment: Don't forget to set the question to answered, so people can see that it's been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue came from your path call.

Your route is:

```
.when('/edition_etude/:idEtude/:domaine', {
    templateUrl: 'vues/edition_etude.html',
    controller: 'edition_etude'
})
```

So your URL should be

```
$location.path('/edition_etude/' + idEtude + '/' + domaine);
```

instead of

```
$location.path('/edition_etude/'+idEtude+'&domaine='+domaine);
```